# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, argv

```
from sys import argv
class Parser:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hostid, self.templateids = argv
if __name__ == "__main__":
parser = Parser()
```

Пытаюсь запустить передав 2 параметра

```
python3 parser.py 10272 10047
```

Выдает ошибку `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from sys import argv
class Parser:
    def __init__(self):
        _, self.hostid, self.templateids = argv

if __name__ == "__main__":
parser = Parser()
```

Comment: А можно по подробнее? Почему именно так? На будущее чтобы я знал)

Comment: @khalinmaxim ну первый аргумент (индекс 0) — это имя файла который ты запускаешь ;)

Comment: Ну так надо это сразу в ответе писать )